# How am I misunderstanding Big-O of these Java functions?

Tags: java, loops, big-o, complexity-theory

For the first example, this turned out to be: O(n), not sure why though.

Example1:

```
for (k = 0; k <= n / 8; k++) // will be O(n/8) thus, O(n)
     System.out.println(k); // will be O(n)
System.out.println("Hello World!"); // will be O(1) because not in a loop
for (p = n; p >= 1; p--) // will be O(n-1) thus, O(n) 
     System.out.print(p % 2); // not sure what % will do here, but I think it's still O(n)
     // Overall I think it's O(n)
```

For the second example. this turned out to be O(n^2), not sure why.

Example2:

```
for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) // will be O(n-1) or O(n)
     for (m = k + 1; m < n; m++) // will be O(n^2) because nested loop
        System.out.println(k * m); // not sure what this will do but I think it will be O(n^2)
     // Overall I think it's O(n^2)
```

For the third example, this turned out to be O(n), but not sure why.

Example3:

```
for (i = n - 3; i <= n - 1; i++) { // not sure here, maybe O(n-1), thus O(n)
     System.out.println(i); // since it is nested then O(n)
     for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) // since this is the second loop, then O(n^2)
        System.out.println(i + k); // not sure what this will do, but I think it will be O(n^2)
} // Overall I think it's O(n^2)
```

The final example turned out to be O(n^2), also not sure why.

Example4:

```
for (a = 1; a <= n / 3; a++) // will be O(n/3) thus O(n)
     for (b = 1; b <= 2 * n; b++) // since it's a nested loop it will be O(2n^2) thus O(n^2)
        System.out.println(a * b); // not sure what this will do, but I think it will be O(n^2)
     // Overall I think it's O(n^2)
```

Could someone please read through these and explain what I am doing wrong. My reasoning is that we track the 'n' variable because that's what the user has inputted and we see how that grows. If it's a single statement, that's constant time O(1), if it's in a loop that's by default O(n), if it's in a nested loop that's O(n^2).

Comment: Example 3 should be O(n^2) ... Where does it say it is O(n) ?

Comment: 1, 2, and 4 you already have the comments explaining why !

Comment: Example 3: it is `((n) - (n - 3)) * n` which simplifies to `3 * n`, so it is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

Since your guess in examples 1, 2 and 4 is equal to your solution, I'm assuming you only have trouble with example 3.

When you look closely at the first line `for (i = n - 3; i <= n - 1; i++)`, you will see that it goes from `n-3` to `n-1` (inclusive), thus it does not depend on the value of `n`.

```
for (i = n - 3; i <= n - 1; i++) { // O(3), so O(1) (since it'a a constant factor)
    System.out.println(i); // nested, O(1)
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) // O(n)
        System.out.println(i + k); // nested, so O(n)
} // Overall O(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your reasoning seems to be correct.

For example 1, you iterate till `n`. With Big O notation, you only care what the runtime complexity is in the limit. Therefore, `2n` becomes `n`, so `O(n)`.

For example 2, your runtime complexity is greater than `n` because you basically iterate till you reach `n`, and during each iteration you iterate untill you reached the number of that iteration. So it's more than `n`, but it's less than `n^2`. But Big O is an upper limit, so you write down `O(n^2)`.

For example 3, take a close loop at the first for loop. Whatever `n` is, you will only execute what is inside the block 4 times (which is a constant amount of times). The nested for loop is just like example 1, so `O(n)`.

For example 4, the first for loop is `O(n)` (like you said, `O(n/3)` becomes `O(n)`). The nested for loop is much the same. `O(n*2)` becomes `O(n)`. Therefore, it's `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Let me go through each of your examples and try to explain the reasoning behind the time complexity.

Your example:

```
for (k = 0; k <= n / 8; k++) // will be O(n/8) thus, O(n)
     System.out.println(k); // will be O(n)
System.out.println("Hello World!"); // will be O(1) because not in a loop
for (p = n; p >= 1; p--) // will be O(n-1) thus, O(n) 
     System.out.print(p % 2); // not sure what % will do here, but I think it's still O(n)
     // Overall I think it's O(n)
```

Explanation:
This is O(n) because we see that the first loop runs `n` times and the second loop runs `n` times. When calculating the complexity, we get this `O(n + n) => O(2n)`. Now we simplify the answer the remove the constants because they "irrelevant" (<= they aren't exactly irrelevant, we just don't count them).

Your example:

```
for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) // will be O(n-1) or O(n)
     for (m = k + 1; m < n; m++) // will be O(n^2) because nested loop
        System.out.println(k * m); // not sure what this will do but I think it will be O(n^2)
     // Overall I think it's O(n^2)
```

Explanation:
Now we have an outer loop that runs `n` times, and an inner loop that runs `n` times. That means that our total time is `O(n*n) => O(n^2)`. That's pretty self-explanatory.

Your example:

```
for (i = n - 3; i <= n - 1; i++) { // not sure here, maybe O(n-1), thus O(n)
     System.out.println(i); // since it is nested then O(n)
     for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) // since this is the second loop, then O(n^2)
        System.out.println(i + k); // not sure what this will do, but I think it will be O(n^2)
} // Overall I think it's O(n^2)
```

Explanation:
Because the first for loop is running from `n - 3` to `n - 1` your loop is not dependent on the value of `n`. So we only count the inner loop which makes `O(n)`

Your example:

```
for (a = 1; a <= n / 3; a++) // will be O(n/3) thus O(n)
     for (b = 1; b <= 2 * n; b++) // since it's a nested loop it will be O(2n^2) thus O(n^2)
        System.out.println(a * b); // not sure what this will do, but I think it will be O(n^2)
     // Overall I think it's O(n^2)
```

Explanation:
The difference between this and the above code is that this outer for loop is dependent on the value of `n`. As `n` grows, `n/3` will also grow (as opposed to `n - 3` and `n - 1`. This makes it `O(n^2)`.